# List files that occur lexically after/greater than a given prefix (or, run database upgrade scripts in a proper order)

Tags: bash, shell-script, mysql

I'm trying to create a shell script that runs through a bunch of SQL scripts.

I've these files:

```
$ ls upgrade/
01-foo.sql 02-bar.sql 02-baz.sql 03-foo1.sql 04-buz.sql
```

And I've got the version of the current db, e.g. `DB_VERSION=02`

How can I now easily loop through and glob the files with a prefix greater than my $DB_VERSION, and run them in order ?

i.e. I'd like to do

```
for f in ???? ; do 
   mysql < $f
done
```

and, with DB_VERSION=02, run the `03-foo1.sql` and `04-buz.sql` , in that order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initial setup: `touch 01-foo.sql 02-bar.sql 02-baz.sql 03-foo1.sql 04-buz.sql 09-quux.sql 10-lala.sql 99-omg.sql`

Actual code: `curr=02; for file in ??-*.sql; do ver="${file:0:2}"; [ "$ver" -gt "$curr" ] && echo "$file"; done`

I.e., define the current version to be `02` and then look at all files (the globbing is alphabetical), executing them if their number prefix is numerically greater. Substitute `mysql` (or what have you) for `echo`.

Comment: have to be careful with invalid octal values: `[[ "08" -gt "07" ]] && echo y` produces `[[: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")` -- you probably want to stick with string comparison.

Comment: glenn jackman: hmm, that's only if you use `[[` instead of `[`. Both are built-in, so I do not immediately see the benefit of using `[[` here. Am I missing something?

Comment: I didn't realize they act differently in this regard. The main benefit of `[[` is additional operators: `==` and `!=` do glob-style pattern matching and `=~` does regex matching. No word splitting is performed in `[[`, so there are fewer surprises if you forget to quote variables. documentation: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-g_t_005b_005b-57

Comment: If you do want to use `[[`, you can tell bash to treat the numbers as decimal regardless of the leading 0: `[[ "10#$ver" -gt "10#$curr" ]]`

Comment: glenn jackman: thanks, I knew about those extra features of `[[` (that's why I wondered why it was preferable *here*), apart from the base specifier. Neat!

Answer (score 0):

In zsh:

```
DB_VERSION=02
glob="<$((DB_VERSION+1))->"
for x in $~glob-*; do mysql <$x; done
```

The `<LOW-UP>` [glob operator](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators) matches integers in a range. You can only use a literal integer, not the result of a computation. Hence, we first build a glob pattern as the value of a parameter, then use this parameter as a glob pattern thanks to the `~` [parameter expansion option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-GLOB_005fSUBST_002c-toggle).